# Track a Adobe Flash app hosted on multiple domains with Google Analytics

Tags: flash, google, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I'm working on a flash app that's gonna be distributed to more and more partners (and obviously domains). It needs to be tracked **aggregated and also separately**.

I implemented Google Analytics using [gaforflash](http://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/), tracking virtual pageviews and events inside the flash app.

What I want to achieve:

- View an **aggregated report** of all partners.
- Identify the partner not by the domain (where the flash is used), but by a **partnerID**.
- **Each partner** needs access to the **report of his domain**. (no admin rights needed)

I came up with this solution:

- Using only one "Web property" in Google Analytics.

  - `UA-XXXXXX-4`
  - `.example.com`
- Set a **custom/virtual hostname** per partner. (GA's "utmhn" parameter)

  - `partner1.example.com`
  - `partner2.example.com`
- Create a profile for each partner, setting the filter to include only the relevant "subdomain"

Problems that came up:

- The gaforflash library doesn't support overriding the host name.

  - Possible workaround: The gaforflash source code is available, so I could add the functionality.
- Any goal from the "master" profile is **not** copied to the partners profile.

  - profile 1: include traffic from hostname `^partner1\.`
  - profile 2: include traffic from hostname `^partner2\.`

---

Is it (very) bad to *fake* the hostname?
Are there better approaches?
Or what improvements could you think of?

**UPDATE:**

I'm looking primarily for a solid data structure inside Google Analytics **regardless of** the **flash** implementation. The only limitations:

- We need an aggregated view across all partners
- Our partners need to have access to their subset of data
- We want to identify the partner by a custom partnerID, not the domain

Answer (score 1):

Less of an answer and more of a pointer, but you might like to look into [cross-domain tracking.](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html)

Using that set up, it appears you could create a single profile in Google Analytics, send all data back to that profile to get the aggregated report of all partners, then modify your single cross-domain profile [as detailed here](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html#profilesKey) to create a filter to sort by individual domains, or set a [custom variable](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html) to track by partnerID.

To offer partner report data, it might be worth building a simple report system hosted on your own site using the [Analytics APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/) instead of providing full access to spoofed subdomain profiles.

You may also like to consider other analytics software. [Omniture SiteCatalyst](http://www.omniture.com/en/products/online_analytics/sitecatalyst) (from Adobe) looks promising: page 21 of the [documentation](http://issuu.com/carismarie/docs/omniture_flash_documentation) suggests that it can be used to track Flash application installs and events across multiple domains. I'm not sure if it offers sub-accounts/client access, but the reporting features look good, and they also offer a [reports API](https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/documentation).

[Webtrends](http://www.webtrends.com/Products/Analytics/Web) offers Flash/application tracking too.